# Arranging responsive imageview in Bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I am trying to maintain 2 columns in  a page where the left column is an image and right column is  description text. Now to maintain the responsive property, my model must follow the feature that when the screen resolution is lower it automatically manages the image to fit the container width.
Now the problem is-the image and paragraph are auto-arranging themselves one under another whenever the screen size is small -But the image failing to take the full width when its auto-arranged. or taking more width when the image size is bigger(**I could not manually give the image size because it would make the image size be a bar in variating screen resolutions**)

Now I am giving the codes..

```css
#main_head {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

#main_head img {
  width: auto;
  height: 480px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NewsPaper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./NewsStyle.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>THE News Daily</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid black;padding: 10px;">

      <h3 class="text-center">The Most Important Article!</h3>
      <div class="col-md-6 "><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIbyw.png"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>
          <h4>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
            looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
            of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..",
            comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their
            exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham. Nulla commodo tincidunt massa, id tincidunt massa sodales nec. Suspendisse quis commodo erat, ac iaculis libero. Nulla laoreet tempus eros, sit amet
            scelerisque enim. Vestibulum sed facilisis ante, a eleifend arcu. Morbi porta elit sit amet auctor semper. Ut laoreet turpis eu justo vestibulum, nec tincidunt nisi fermentum. Quisque vehicula elementum massa, a convallis ante maximus et.
            Donec et auctor ex. Sed eu venenatis neque. Sed faucibus semper ullamcorper. Pellentesque sodales non magna et vehicula. Ut vel ultricies ex, in feugiat est.<a>read more >>></a> </h4>
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How is it possible to obtain the objective? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "col-6" class (without using xs,md,lg etc). That will divide the container to two on any screen width:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIbyw.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text...</p>
    <a>read more >>></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about bootstrap grid system here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

As for the image, you can try using bootstrap classes in order to set responsiveness: "Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element."

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" />
```

Another approach will be using the object-fit as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Some side-notes: h4 can't be child of p, and elements inside .row (like your h3) should be wrapped with .col-x class (in your case col-12).

Hope that helps.